# ajax fetch same data from database every time

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am trying to develop a complaint management system where the admin can view complaints one by one.Complaints would be displayed in tabular format but with fewer details.I have kept a view button which upon pressing will display a detailed description of a complaint in a modal.Here I have used jquery and ajax apart from jstl.But every time I click on the view button the first complaint is displayed.Here is the details of my implementation kindly help

**Bean Classes**

```
package tat.beans;

public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private String department;
    private String emailid;

    public User() {
        this("", "", "", "", "", "","");
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String role, String name, String designation, String department,String emailid) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.name = name;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.department = department;
        this.setEmailid(emailid);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
    }

    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }

}

package tat.beans;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Complaint {

    private int complaintNumber;
    private Date dateOfIncident;
    private String grievanceType;
    private String accusedInfo;
    private String emailId;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String descriptionOfIncident;
    private String witness;
    private String otherVictims;
    private String wellWishers;
    private Timestamp submittime;
    private String status;
    private String userName;

    public Complaint() {
        this(0, null, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", null, "", "");
    }

    public Complaint(int complaintNumber, Date dateOfIncident, String grievanceType, String accusedInfo, String emailId, String contactNumber, String descriptionOfIncident, String witness, String otherVictims, String wellWishers, Timestamp submittime, String status, String userName) {
        this.complaintNumber = complaintNumber;
        this.dateOfIncident = dateOfIncident;
        this.grievanceType = grievanceType;
        this.accusedInfo = accusedInfo;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.descriptionOfIncident = descriptionOfIncident;
        this.witness = witness;
        this.otherVictims = otherVictims;
        this.wellWishers = wellWishers;
        this.submittime = submittime;
        this.status = status;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getComplaintNumber() {
        return complaintNumber;
    }

    public void setComplaintNumber(int complaintNumber) {
        this.complaintNumber = complaintNumber;
    }

    public Date getDateOfIncident() {
        return dateOfIncident;
    }

    public void setDateOfIncident(Date dateOfIncident) {
        this.dateOfIncident = dateOfIncident;
    }

    public String getGrievanceType() {
        return grievanceType;
    }

    public void setGrievanceType(String grievanceType) {
        this.grievanceType = grievanceType;
    }

    public String getAccusedInfo() {
        return accusedInfo;
    }

    public void setAccusedInfo(String accusedInfo) {
        this.accusedInfo = accusedInfo;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getDescriptionOfIncident() {
        return descriptionOfIncident;
    }

    public void setDescriptionOfIncident(String descriptionOfIncident) {
        this.descriptionOfIncident = descriptionOfIncident;
    }

    public String getWitness() {
        return witness;
    }

    public void setWitness(String witness) {
        this.witness = witness;
    }

    public String getOtherVictims() {
        return otherVictims;
    }

    public void setOtherVictims(String otherVictims) {
        this.otherVictims = otherVictims;
    }

    public String getWellWishers() {
        return wellWishers;
    }

    public void setWellWishers(String wellWishers) {
        this.wellWishers = wellWishers;
    }

    public Timestamp getSubmittime() {
        return submittime;
    }

    public void setSubmittime(Timestamp submittime) {
        this.submittime = submittime;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Complaint [complaintNumber=" + complaintNumber + ", dateOfIncident=" + dateOfIncident
                + ", grievanceType=" + grievanceType + ", accusedInfo=" + accusedInfo + ", emailId=" + emailId
                + ", contactNumber=" + contactNumber + ", descriptionOfIncident=" + descriptionOfIncident + ", witness="
                + witness + ", otherVictims=" + otherVictims + ", wellWishers=" + wellWishers + ", submittime="
                + submittime + ", status=" + status + ", userName=" + userName + "]";
    }
    
}
```

**Data Access Class**

```
package tat.data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import tat.beans.Complaint;
import tat.beans.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Date;

public class UserDBUtil {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public UserDBUtil(DataSource theDataSource) {
        dataSource = theDataSource;
    }

    public User getUser(String username, String password) {
        Connection myConn = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        User theUser = null;
        try {
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();// get db connection
            String sql = "select * from tatuserinfo " + "where username=?";// sql for retrieval
            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

            // set the param values for the user
            myStmt.setString(1, username);

            // execute sql select
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
            if (myRs.next()) {
                if (myRs.getString("password").equals(password)) {
                    theUser = new User(myRs.getString(1), myRs.getString(2), myRs.getString(3), myRs.getString(4),
                            myRs.getString(5), myRs.getString(6), myRs.getString(7));
                    // return theUser;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // clean up JDBC objects
            close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);
        }
        return theUser;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> insertComplaint(Complaint C) {
        Connection myConn = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet generatedKeys = null;
        Map<String, Integer> hashMap = null;
        try {
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();
            String sql = "insert into grievdb(DATEOFINCIDENT,GRIEVANCETYPE,ACCUSEDINFO,EMAILID,CONTACTNUMBER,DESCRIPTIONOFINCIDENT,"
                    + "WITNESS,OTHERVICTIMS,WELLWISHERS,SUBMITTIME,STATUS,USERNAME)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            String generatedColumns[] = { "COMPLAINTNUMBER" };// for oracle database only
            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql, generatedColumns);
            myStmt.setDate(1, C.getDateOfIncident());
            myStmt.setString(2, C.getGrievanceType());
            myStmt.setString(3, C.getAccusedInfo());
            myStmt.setString(4, C.getEmailId());
            myStmt.setString(5, C.getContactNumber());
            myStmt.setString(6, C.getDescriptionOfIncident());
            myStmt.setString(7, C.getWitness());
            myStmt.setString(8, C.getOtherVictims());
            myStmt.setString(9, C.getWellWishers());
            myStmt.setTimestamp(10, C.getSubmittime());
            myStmt.setString(11, C.getStatus());
            myStmt.setString(12, C.getUserName());
            if (myStmt.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                generatedKeys = myStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    int complaintNumber = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
                    hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    hashMap.put("result", 1);
                    hashMap.put("complaintNumber", complaintNumber);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(myConn, myStmt, null);
        }

        return hashMap;

    }

    public Complaint getComplaint(int complaintNumber) throws Exception {
        Connection myConn = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        Complaint tempComplaint = null;
        try {
            // get a connection
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            // create sql statement
            String sql = "select * from grievdb where COMPLAINTNUMBER=?";

            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
            myStmt.setInt(1, complaintNumber);
            // execute query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
            if(myRs.next()) {
                int cnumber = myRs.getInt("COMPLAINTNUMBER");
                Date date = myRs.getDate("DATEOFINCIDENT");
                String category = myRs.getString("GRIEVANCETYPE");
                String accused = myRs.getString("ACCUSEDINFO");
                String email = myRs.getString("EMAILID");
                String contactNumber = myRs.getString("CONTACTNUMBER");
                String description = myRs.getString("DESCRIPTIONOFINCIDENT");
                String witness = myRs.getString("WITNESS");
                String victims = myRs.getString("OTHERVICTIMS");
                String wellWishers = myRs.getString("WELLWISHERS");
                Timestamp submitTime = myRs.getTimestamp("SUBMITTIME");
                String status = myRs.getString("STATUS");
                String userName = myRs.getString("USERNAME");

                tempComplaint = new Complaint(cnumber, date, category, accused, email, contactNumber, description,
                        witness, victims, wellWishers, submitTime, status, userName);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }finally {
            close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);
        }
        return tempComplaint;
    }

    public ArrayList<Complaint> getComplaints() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Complaint> complaints = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        // create new Complaint object
        Complaint tempComplaint;
        try {
            // get a connection
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            // create sql statement
            String sql = "select * from grievdb where status='PENDING' OR status='FORWARDED' order by COMPLAINTNUMBER";

            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            // execute query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

            // process result set
            while (myRs.next()) {

                // retrieve data from result set row
                int cnumber = myRs.getInt("COMPLAINTNUMBER");
                Date date = myRs.getDate("DATEOFINCIDENT");
                String category = myRs.getString("GRIEVANCETYPE");
                String accused = myRs.getString("ACCUSEDINFO");
                String email = myRs.getString("EMAILID");
                String contactNumber = myRs.getString("CONTACTNUMBER");
                String description = myRs.getString("DESCRIPTIONOFINCIDENT");
                String witness = myRs.getString("WITNESS");
                String victims = myRs.getString("OTHERVICTIMS");
                String wellWishers = myRs.getString("WELLWISHERS");
                Timestamp submitTime = myRs.getTimestamp("SUBMITTIME");
                String status = myRs.getString("STATUS");
                String userName = myRs.getString("USERNAME");

                tempComplaint = new Complaint(cnumber, date, category, accused, email, contactNumber, description,
                        witness, victims, wellWishers, submitTime, status, userName);

                // add it to the list of students
                complaints.add(tempComplaint);
            }

            return complaints;
        } finally {
            // close JDBC objects
            myStmt.close();
            close(myConn, null, myRs);
        }
    }

    private void close(Connection myConn, PreparedStatement myStmt, ResultSet myRs) {

        try {
            if (myRs != null) {
                myRs.close();
            }

            if (myStmt != null) {
                myStmt.close();
            }

            if (myConn != null) {
                myConn.close(); // doesn't really close it ... just puts back in connection pool
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Servlet Function which send data to ajax call**

```
private void fetchComplaintwithComplaintNumber(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        int complaintNumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("compNumber"));
        Complaint comp = userDbUtil.getComplaint(complaintNumber);
        if (comp != null)
            response.getWriter().print(comp);
        else
            response.getWriter().print("db operation failed");
    }
```

**jsp page which fetch data using both jstl and ajax**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : list-complaints.jsp
    Created on : 10 July, 2020, 1:58:15 PM
    Author     : jeetu
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<!--  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#viewdetails').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("value");
            $.ajax({
                url : 'MainController',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {
                    compNumber : id,
                    command : "FETCHCOMPLAINT"
                },
                success : function(resultText) {
                    $('#show-data').html(resultText);
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log('Error occured!!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Trident Grievance Redressal Cell</h1>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Complaint Number</th>
                    <th>category</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Change Category</th>
                    <th>Forward to</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <c:forEach var="tempComplaints" items="${COMPLAINT_LIST}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${tempComplaints.complaintNumber}</td>
                    <td>${tempComplaints.grievanceType}</td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="viewdetails"
                            value="${tempComplaints.complaintNumber}">View</button> <!-- Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Complaint Details</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: justify;">
                                        <div id="show-data"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><select id="category">
                            <option value="general">General</option>
                            <option value="women">Women</option>
                            <option value="sc/st">SC/ST</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select id="committee">
                            <option value="generalhead">General Head</option>
                            <option value="womenhead">Women Head</option>
                            <option value="sc/sthead">SC/ST Head</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `id=viewdetails` inside a loop - therefore each of your buttons has the same id - IDs must be unique - `$("#id")` will only access the first one.  Give your buttons a class and use `$(".viewdetails")`

Comment: You also have `id=show-data` inside the loop and `$("#show-data").html(...)` will only update the first one - same issue.

Comment: I followed your instructions and made necessary changes but it did not fetch anything.Then Instead using class attribute I used name attribute  like this $('[name="viewDetails"]') and it worked fine for me.By the way thanks a lot for giving me valuable insights